# __subclasses__() returns different subclasses in debugging mode and running

Tags: python, inheritance, subclassing

I am learning inheritance and wrote a simple function to visualize subclasses, here is the code:

```
def PrintClassTree(thisclass, nest=0):
    if nest > 1:
        print('   |' * (nest - 1), end='')

    if nest > 0:
        print('   +---', end='')


    print(thisclass.__name__)

    for subclass in thisclass.__subclasses__():
        PrintClassTree(subclass, nest+1)

PrintClassTree(dict)
```

when I ran the function I got

```
dict
   +---OrderedDict
   +---defaultdict
   +---Counter
```

This is different from directly calling `dict.__subclasses__()`. When I ran in debugging mode, I got the following list, the same as calling `dict.__subclasses__()`

```
dict
   +---OrderedDict
   +---defaultdict
   |   +---Quoter
   +---Counter
   +---_EnumDict
   +---_QByteMap
   +---StgDict
   +---_ReqExtras
   +---ZipManifests
   |   +---MemoizedZipManifests
   +---TypedDict
```

I tried `list` and again, I can only get a full list of subclasses in debugging mode. I feel I am missing something here, but what makes debugging different from running the function?

I use Pycharm so both were done in the same IDLE. I couldn't find anything on this behavior. I tried `BaseException` and this seems to give me correct results when running the function.

Comment: It's likely that in debug mode, your interpreter has a lot of extra modules loaded. The list of subclasses returned by the `__subclasses__()` method only describes the ones that have been loaded already, there might be dozens more in module that haven't been loaded (yet). You can write your own new subclasses all day, but they'll only show up in the list after they've been loaded into the interpreter.

Comment: Thank you @Blckknght. I tried a print statement `print(dict.__subclasses__()`, when running the function, it only prints out the first three. They are all collections. Interesting. I suspect the rest of the subclasses may be useful for debugging and interactive mode, but not when running the full script? Thanks again for answering my question